# Consultas a Postgresql con Sequelize dejan de funcionar repentinamente

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, excepciones, heroku, sequelize.js

Actualmente estoy a cargo de un sistema desarrollado en NodeJS, que usa como base de datos a PostgreSQL, y accedemos a ella usando el ORM Sequelize, todo esto en la plataforma de Heroku.

El problema que enfrento es que, en cierto punto, intenté realizar un nuevo deploy con cambios en algunas funcionalidades, pero pasados 1 o 2 minutos después de haber realizado el deploy, todas las consultas a base de datos empiezan a generar el mismo error, descrito en el siguiente log:

```
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619517+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619534+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.once (events.js:307:11)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619535+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.connect (net.js:943:10)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619536+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrappedConnect (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/core/net.js:53:31)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619536+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapped (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:183:28)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619537+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Tracer.addSegment (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/transaction/tracer/index.js:83:48)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619538+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.connectWrapper [as connect] (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/core/net.js:43:27)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619539+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:42:17)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619540+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Client.connect (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:47:9)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619540+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.tap.query (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:56:16)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619541+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.wrappedExecutorCaller [as _resolveFromResolver] (/app/node_modules/newrelic/lib/instrumentation/promise.js:200:18)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619542+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:69:37)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ConnectionManager.connect     (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:52:10)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ConnectionManager.$connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:204:41)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.create (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:74:14)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at createResource (/app/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:261:13)
2017-03-09T16:17:10.619546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at dispense (/app/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:253:9)
```

Como se ve (a menos que lo esté viendo mal), el log no hace referencia a ningún método, archivo, a ningún punto del proyecto, solamente a librerías (las que se encuentra dentro de `node_modules`). Incluso esperaría que en el tope de la pila de errores apareciera cual es la consulta Sequelize que genera error, pero no es una sola, para todas genera lo mismo.

Este mismo deploy lo he probado tanto en local como en un servidor de staging, que es otra aplicación de Heroku para pruebas, y no se genera ese error. Solamente me aparece en tiempo de producción.

He logrado dejar el sistema estable haciendo rollback al ultimo commit exitoso, pero aquí surge otro problema que desemboca en el mismo registro de error. Si intento hacer commit&push del mismo código asociado a ese punto del sistema, empieza a generarse el mismo error, incluso cuando técnicamente no estoy subiendo nada nuevo, solo una copia del código (digamos que con un espacio en blanco de más solamente) que actualmente está funcionando bien en el servidor.

Agradecería alguna ayuda, si es que he dejado algún detalle técnico o metodológico en el camino. Por supuesto ya he buscado en internet, pero sin resultados positivos.

Comment: ¿De casualidad estás usando Node.js 7.7.2?

Comment: podrías poner el código con que inicias el webserver? Ese error se produce cuando pasas un string u objeto a algo que esperaba una función. A mí me ha pasado (por errores mios) en aplicaciones que utilizan express o connect

Comment: @GustavoGarcía acabo de revisar los logs del build en Heroku y si instala esa versión. ¿Que relación tendría?

Comment: @amenadiel pero en ese caso que planteas el servidor ni siquiera iniciaría, no? A mi el servidor me inicia sin problemas, es a los 30 segundos o al minuto como máximo que empieza a dar error solamente en las consultas a base de datos. De resto las cargas de las vistas y las respuestas en endpoints que no utilizan consultas a base de datos (que son muy pocos) funcionan sin problema.

Comment: Hay un par de bugs similares a los tuyos con la versión 7.7.2 que han sido reportados. Prueba haciendo un downgrade a 7.7.1.

Comment: Empecé a investigar en base al criterio que planteas, y si, hay info similar a lo que planteo. Voy a revisar de acuerdo a eso, y cualquier cosa les comento.

Comment: Definitivamente si era lo que comentaste @GustavoGarcía, realicé el deploy haciendo el downgrade y ahora si funciona. Aunque ahora me queda la duda de porque en el servidor de staging, en el que estuve trabajando con la versión 7.7.2, no me causó ese problema. Tendrá que ver con la infraestructura de los deploys de Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la colaboración de Gustavo en los comentarios a mi pregunta, y a par de links que revisé:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11761

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699529/error-typeerror-listener-argument-must-be-a-function-in-node-7-7-2

Verifiqué que el problema estaba siendo causado por la actualización que Heroku realizó de manera automática (en base a los criterios de mi `package.json`) sobre la versión de Node, así que indiqué en ese mismo archivo que instalara específicamente la versión `7.7.1` que fué la última que nos funcionaba sin problemas, y no la `7.7.2` que estaba causando el error.